# MongoDB updateOne({$pull}) is matching a document, but not removing it from an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

I am building a Pokemon API MERN based app where users can search Pokemon from a search component and add them to their profile. The User schema contains an array of Pokemon, where each Pokemon is represented by a document containing the Pokedex number, the name of the Pokemon, and an array of sprite source links so that each Pokemon can be mapped to the user's profile. I am using the $push operator to add each Pokemon from a search result to the user's team from a put request, which works fine. Just like in the actual game, each user is limited to having 6 Pokemon on their team at one time, but a user's team can also contain duplicates of the same Pokemon, so in order to remove a Pokemon from a user's team I send a put request of the username of the user currently logged in as well as the _id of the Pokemon to be deleted. When I try this request, it returns an error saying that n:1 has been matched, but the document is not pulled from the user's array of Pokemon.

```
router.put("/del", auth, async (req, res) => {
  // Find user
  User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }).then((user) => {
    // Try updating Pokemon array
    const offTeam = user
      .updateOne({ $pull: { pokemon: { _id: req.body.id } } }, function(
        err,
        data
      ) {
        console.log("ERROR:", err, data, err.message);
      })
      .then((offTeam) => {
        res.status(200).json(offTeam);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: e.message });
      });
  });
});
```

Below is the error that is returned:

```
ERROR: null {
  n: 1,
  nModified: 0,
  opTime: {
    ts: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 2, high_: 1605810353 },
    t: 4
  },
  electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000004,
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 2, high_: 1605810353 },
    signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 2, high_: 1605810353 }
}
```

EDIT: Link to the repo, currently working in the delete branch.
https://github.com/nrhill1/pokeMERN/tree/delete

EDIT: Here's an example of my profile. I am trying to delete Marill and Houndoom, but neither will pull.

```
    _id
    :5fb5ef14e664d5172ee5e1ed
    username
    :"nic"
    email
    :"nic@gmail.com"
    password
    :"$2a$10$kKfpdkmPMeWAS.22nulCSOkVeqKPGxiA5PL9D5WhPsU0pAznq/J2u"
    pokemon
    :
    Array
        0
        :
        Object
            _id
            :5fb5ef26e664d5172ee5e1ee
            id
            :229
            name
            :"houndoom"
            sprites
            :
            Array
        1
        :
        Object
            _id
            :5fb614318558521aac650a4c
            id
            :183
            name
            :"marill"
            sprites
            :
            Array
                0
                :"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokem..."
                1
                :"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokem..."
    reg_date
    :2020-11-19T04:05:40.436+00:00
    __v
    :0
```

Comment: Can you post an example of a document and the expected output?

Comment: @J.F. Edited the post and added my user profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$in` and set the ids you want to pull into an array like this (I think this is the easiest way for the future if you want to add more elements):

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "5fb5ef14e664d5172ee5e1ed",
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "pokemon": {
      "id": {
        "$in": [
          229,
          183
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "multi": true
})
```

The query first match by `_id` (user id I guess, but you can use `username`, `email` or other field if you want) and then pull all pokemons where `id` is inside the array. In this case `229` and `183` will be deleted.
Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/U9PfiFhP1s5)

Note that `multi:true` is not necessary if you use the method `updateMany()`.

Using mongoose is the same query but using `updateMany()`:

```js
var idToUpdate = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.id)
var pokemonsToDelete = [229, 183]
var updated = await model.updateMany({
  "_id": idToUpdate,
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "pokemon": {
      "id": {
        "$in": pokemonsToDelete
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Try parsing `req.body.id` to `ObjectId`. Something like this: `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.id)`

Comment: I've tested and it works for me. Maybe are you missing share anything tah could change the query or any missing value?

Comment: Ok, so I think you misread my original question. I can't use the pokedex number because then it would not allow the user to delete a copy of a duplicate pokemon on their team. If I wanted a team of all Pikachu, this query would delete every single Pikachu whenever I just wanted to remove one.

Comment: So you want to delete by pokemon `_id`? Then use this field instead of `id`.

Comment: No brainer! Thank you so much for your help. The fix was to wrap _id in the mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id).